# Vue directive with classList.add doesn't immediately update the DOM element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

Adding a custom class name to an element via the directive takes tons of time. The element is rendered, then after a few seconds, the class gets added. The effect is not immediate, which is extremely weird.

Both `bind` and `update` have the same function. The directive is called via `v-my-directive={active: false}`, where `active` is a boolean that changes after 3-4 seconds

The function's content:

```js
bind(el, payload) {
    const value = payload ? payload.value : null;
    if(!value) return;
    const active = value.active;
    process(el, active);
}
```

The function `process` is straight forward

```js
function process(el, active) {
   if(!el) return;
   if(active) el.classList.add("my-class");
   if(!active) el.classList.remove("my-class");
}
```

This directive is implemented in 5 components only.

Expected

- The directive adds the content directly to the classes list.

Actual:

- The directive gets called. It process the function and executes the insertion of the new class.
- The DOM element doesn't get the new class until a few seconds later, and if I try to add multiple classes, there's a delay between them.

I've tried subtracting the `Date.now()`, its value is `0`. There's no delay in the actual code, just a delay in insertion of the classes.

I've also tried `className += "my-class"`, which is also as slow as the second one.

The slowness happens to the DOM element's update, not the actual code.

I appreciate any ideas / thoughts regarding this issue.

Comment: Consider providing a way to reproduce the problem as this is not something obvious and needs to be debugged. There's no such thing in Vue that would provide 3-4 second delays. The obvious explanations are that you debugged it the wrong way, or the update is expensive and blocks the main thread. If you need it to be executed earlier, you probably need an earlier hook https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#directive-hooks .  But generally that delay looks like the primary problem here